# How can I change QGraphicsView background using check box

Tags: c++, qt, background, qt5, qgraphicsview

In this code,which change the `QGraphicsView` background.Now I need to change the background when I check true `checkBox`.When I set to `checkBox` to check `true` I need to set the background like this code.When I set `checkBox` to check `false`. I need to set `QGraphicsView` for normal default way. How can I do this.

here is my code:

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QGraphicsTextItem>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    scene = new Scene(this);
    scene->setSceneRect(10,10,260,200);
    view = new QGraphicsView(scene);
    setCentralWidget(view);
}
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include "scene.h"
#include "customrectitem.h"

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
private:
    QGraphicsView* view;
    QGraphicsScene* scene;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**Scene.h**

```
#ifndef SCENE_H
#define SCENE_H

#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QApplication>

class Scene : public QGraphicsScene
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Scene(QObject *parent = 0);
    int getGridSize() const {return this->gridSize;}

protected:
    void drawBackground (QPainter* painter, const QRectF &rect);
private:
    int gridSize;

};

#endif // SCENE_H
```

**Scene.cpp**

```
#include "scene.h"

Scene::Scene(QObject *parent) : QGraphicsScene(parent), gridSize(20)
{
    Q_ASSERT(gridSize > 0);
}

void Scene::drawBackground(QPainter *painter, const QRectF &rect)
{
        QColor c (10,140,255,155);
        painter->setPen(c);
        qreal left = int(rect.left()) - (int(rect.left()) % gridSize);
        qreal top = int(rect.top()) - (int(rect.top()) % gridSize);
        QVarLengthArray<QLineF,100> lines;
        for (qreal x = left; x < rect.right(); x += gridSize)
            lines.append(QLineF(x,rect.top(),x,rect.bottom()));

        for (qreal y = top; y < rect.bottom(); y += gridSize)
            lines.append(QLineF(rect.left(),y,rect.right(),y));
        painter->drawLines(lines.data(),lines.size());
}
```

Comment: @eyllanesc I tried your solution, But I couldn't setup that solution to my project. I don't understand how to solve it. this is my project [link](https://github.com/sachithmw/Stackover) please check it and give me a solution sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although [@Scheff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7478597/scheff)'s solution is good, it has the following problems:

- the first solution makes it only cover a small space, if you change the size of QGraphicsView it will not cover all the space.
- The second solution has the problem that you are using the `viewport()` coordinate, and not the scene, if you add an item and then enlarge the QGraphicsView without moving the item, then you see a scroll.

Initial:

[image]

After changing the size:

[image]

A solution that corrects both errors is to overwrite the [drawBackground](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#drawBackground) method of QGraphicsScene:

```
#ifndef GRAPHICSSCENE_H
#define GRAPHICSSCENE_H

#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QPainter>


class GraphicsScene: public QGraphicsScene{

    int mGridSize;
    QColor mGridColor;
    bool mGridVisible;

    Q_OBJECT
public:
    GraphicsScene(QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR):QGraphicsScene(parent),
        mGridSize(20), mGridColor(0x0a8affu), mGridVisible(true)
    {

    }
    bool gridVisible() const {
        return mGridVisible;
    }
    void setGridVisible(bool gridVisible){
        if(mGridVisible != gridVisible){
            mGridVisible = gridVisible;
            update();
        }
    }
protected:
    void drawBackground(QPainter *painter, const QRectF &rect){
        if(mGridVisible) {
            QRect r = rect.toRect();
            int xmin  =r.left() - r.left()%mGridSize - mGridSize;
            int ymin = r.top() - r.top()%mGridSize - mGridSize;
            int xmax = r.right() - r.right()%mGridSize + mGridSize;
            int ymax = r.bottom() - r.bottom()%mGridSize + mGridSize;
            for(int x=xmin ; x <= xmax; x += mGridSize ){
                painter->drawLine(x, r.top(), x, r.bottom());
            }

            for(int y=ymin ; y <= ymax; y+= mGridSize ){
                painter->drawLine(r.left(), y, r.right(), y);
            }
        }
    }
};

#endif // GRAPHICSSCENE_H
```

The advantage of this solution is that it does not load any new object, besides that the graph is in the coordinates of the scene, so there is no displacement of the second solution.

Initial:

[image]

After changing the size:

[image]

<sub>The complete example can be found at the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/47728237)</sub>

Comment: sir,I'm tried to setup your code to my project.But there have some difficulties to do.so here I attach my project link. [link](https://github.com/sachithmw/Stackover) please tell me how can I do this(your answer) for my project.

Comment: @Learner I do not see that you have implemented my code, try it and if you fail then in that moment share the code with what you have tried.

Comment: @Learner You must implement mGridVisible is Scene, and then connect it to the stateChanged signal of QCheckBox as I did in the main.cpp

Comment: I updated github, when I try my program this error message occurred. `The program has unexpectedly finished.` So please check what I didi wrong here. I run my project before use checkbox.

Comment: @Learner uncomment the lines of mainwindow.cpp: `gScene = new Scene(this);
    gScene->setSceneRect(0,0,1000,1000);`, the error is caused by not having created the memory space of the pointer, I did not tell you to comment that part. Do what I told you.

Comment: `gScene` is object of `scene class` which I tried myself previously.  `GrapScene` is object of `GraphicsScene class` you created. I uncomment those code lines.But still error occurring. what I did wrong here.please check my project files and give me a solution  sir.I am stacked with this.

Comment: I do not know what you were doing, I recommend you read the basics of programming, it will be the last time you do your work, the working code is in the following link: https://ufile.io/u86ou

Comment: @eyllanesc Had to read your critics to my code in your answer. (You should've sent me this as a comment.) You're absolutely right. - I would've invested more effort with the resp. feed-back. (but got only the request for upload although the complete source code was exposed. For me, it seems the questioner didn't even recognize this - probably didn't read it completely, just saw the screenshots and thought "want to have". I'm not doing (home-)work for people - just give hints how to solve things.) ;-)

Comment: @Scheff I only comment your answer in mine to see the advantages, your solution is very different from mine. I do the feedback if I think that giving them you can get to the right path, but in your case I saw that it was impossible, so I did not do them, for a next opportunity I will get them to you, and as a comment if you do not see the effort of the author of the question I will avoid answering, or at least I will only post an answer. I try to see the progress of those who ask, if I do not see any there my help ends, unless the question is very good. :P

Answer (score 1):

I have two opportunities in mind to draw a grid:

1. deriving a class from `QGraphicsView` and overloading the `paintEvent()` and drawing the grid before falling back to `QGraphicsView::paintEvent()`
2. adding the grid lines as scene items under a `QGraphicsItemGroup` which allows control of visibility.

The first method has the advantage that it can seamlessly adapt to any resizing of viewport.

This is my sample code `testQGraphicsView-BgGrid.cc`:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

class Canvas: public QGraphicsView {
  private:
    int _gridSize;
    QColor _gridColor;
    bool _gridVisible;

  public:
    explicit Canvas(QWidget *pQParent = nullptr):
      QGraphicsView(pQParent),
      _gridSize(20), _gridColor(0x0a8affu), _gridVisible(true)
    { }

    bool gridVisible() const { return _gridVisible; }
    void setGridVisible(bool gridVisible)
    {
      _gridVisible = gridVisible;
      viewport()->update();
    }

  protected:
    virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *pQEvent) override
    {
      QPainter qPainter(viewport());
      if (_gridVisible) {
        const int wView = viewport()->width(), hView = viewport()->height();
        qPainter.setPen(_gridColor);
        for (int x = _gridSize / 2; x < wView; x += _gridSize) {
          qPainter.drawLine(x, 0, x, hView - 1);
        }
        for (int y = _gridSize / 2; y < hView; y += _gridSize) {
          qPainter.drawLine(0, y, wView - 1, y);
        }
      }
      QGraphicsView::paintEvent(pQEvent);
    }
};

void makeGrid(
  QGraphicsItemGroup &qItemGrp, const QSize &size,
  int gridSize = 20, const QColor &gridColor = 0x0a8affu)
{
  const int wView = size.width(), hView = size.height();
  for (int x = gridSize / 2; x < wView; x += gridSize) {
    QGraphicsLineItem *pQItem = new QGraphicsLineItem(x, 0, x, hView - 1);
    pQItem->setPen(gridColor);
    qItemGrp.addToGroup(pQItem);
  }
  for (int y = gridSize / 2; y < hView; y += gridSize) {
    QGraphicsLineItem *pQItem = new QGraphicsLineItem(0, y, wView - 1, y);
    pQItem->setPen(gridColor);
    qItemGrp.addToGroup(pQItem);
  }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  // setup GUI
  QWidget qWnd;
  QGridLayout qGrid;
  QLabel qLblL(QString::fromUtf8("Grid as part of scene"));
  qGrid.addWidget(&qLblL, 0, 0);
  QCheckBox qTglGridL(QString::fromUtf8("Show Grid"));
  qGrid.addWidget(&qTglGridL, 0, 1);
  QGraphicsView qGraphView;
  qGrid.addWidget(&qGraphView, 1, 0, 1, 2);
  QLabel qLblR(QString::fromUtf8("Grid painted as background"));
  qGrid.addWidget(&qLblR, 0, 2);
  QCheckBox qTglGridR(QString::fromUtf8("Show Grid"));
  qGrid.addWidget(&qTglGridR, 0, 3);
  Canvas canvas;
  qGrid.addWidget(&canvas, 1, 2, 1, 2);
  qWnd.setLayout(&qGrid);
  qWnd.show();
  // init GUI
  QGraphicsScene qGraphSceneL;
  QGraphicsItemGroup qItemGrid;
  makeGrid(qItemGrid, qGraphView.viewport()->size());
  qGraphSceneL.addItem(&qItemGrid);
  qGraphView.setScene(&qGraphSceneL);
  qTglGridL.setCheckState(
    qItemGrid.isVisible() ? Qt::Checked : Qt::Unchecked);
  qTglGridR.setCheckState(
    canvas.gridVisible() ? Qt::Checked : Qt::Unchecked);
  // install signal handlers
  QObject::connect(&qTglGridL, &QCheckBox::stateChanged,
    [&qItemGrid](int state)
    {
      qItemGrid.setVisible(state != Qt::Unchecked);
    });
  QObject::connect(&qTglGridR, &QCheckBox::stateChanged,
    [&canvas](int state)
    {
      canvas.setGridVisible(state != Qt::Unchecked);
    });
  // runtime loop
  return app.exec();
}
```

Compiled with VS2013 and Qt 5.9.2, tested on Window 10 (64 bit):

[image: snapshot of testQGraphicsView-BgGrid]

---

**Update:**

The QMake script `testQGraphicsView-BgGrid.pro`:

```
SOURCES = testQGraphicsView-BgGrid.cc

QT += widgets
```

Building and testing in `bash` on cygwin:

```
$ qmake-qt5 testQGraphicsView-BgGrid.pro

$ make
g++ -c -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -D_GNU_SOURCE -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -isystem /usr/include/qt5 -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtGui -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I. -I/usr/lib/qt5/mkspecs/cygwin-g++ -o testQGraphicsView-BgGrid.o testQGraphicsView-BgGrid.cc
g++  -o testQGraphicsView-BgGrid.exe testQGraphicsView-BgGrid.o   -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread 

$ ./testQGraphicsView-BgGrid
```

The same program as X11 application:

[image: snapshot of testQGraphicsView-BgGrid (cygwin, X11)]

---

**Yet Another Update:**

I've to admit that, in my first version, I focused on **How can I change QGraphicsView background using check box** with emphasis on **check box** ignoring [`QGraphicsScene::drawBackground()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#drawBackground) (which I didn't know) and ignoring issues in the grid rendering itself (which I used instead). As pointed out in [eyllanesc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47734231/7478597), both showed solutions offer some weaknesses which (at least) I should have documented.

1. The left view (which involves the grid into scene) doesn't necessarily fill the `viewport()`. IMHO, this is acceptable if the grid fills the relevant range which is used by scene. (It might be intended to visualize that the scene covers only a part of the `viewport()`.) However, the argument `const QSize &size` of `makeGrid()` was an unlucky choice concerning this intention. I fixed this design issue by replacing it with `const QRect &rect`.
2. The right view (which overloads `paintEvent()`) didn't consider possible scrolling of scene. I fixed this by mapping the upper left corner to scene coordinates (`const QPointF offs = mapToScene(0, 0);`) and consider the offset as start value in the loops.

The update sample code `testQGrapicsView-BgGrid.cc`:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

class Canvas: public QGraphicsView {
  private:
    int _gridSize;
    QColor _gridColor;
    bool _gridVisible;

  public:
    explicit Canvas(QWidget *pQParent = nullptr):
      QGraphicsView(pQParent),
      _gridSize(20), _gridColor(0x0a8affu), _gridVisible(true)
    { }

    bool gridVisible() const { return _gridVisible; }
    void setGridVisible(bool gridVisible)
    {
      _gridVisible = gridVisible;
      viewport()->update();
    }

  protected:
    virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *pQEvent) override
    {
      QPainter qPainter(viewport());
      if (_gridVisible) {
        const int wView = viewport()->width(), hView = viewport()->height();
        const QPointF offs = mapToScene(0, 0);
        qPainter.setPen(_gridColor);
        for (int x = (int)offs.x() % _gridSize; x < wView; x += _gridSize) {
          qPainter.drawLine(x, 0, x, hView - 1);
        }
        for (int y = (int)offs.y() % _gridSize; y < hView; y += _gridSize) {
          qPainter.drawLine(0, y, wView - 1, y);
        }
      }
      QGraphicsView::paintEvent(pQEvent);
    }
};

void makeGrid(
  QGraphicsItemGroup &qItemGrp, const QRect &rect,
  int gridSize = 20, const QColor &gridColor = 0x0a8affu)
{
  for (int x = rect.x(), xE = x + rect.width(); x < xE; x += gridSize) {
    QGraphicsLineItem *pQItem
      = new QGraphicsLineItem(x, rect.y(), x, rect.height() - 1);
    pQItem->setPen(gridColor);
    qItemGrp.addToGroup(pQItem);
  }
  for (int y = rect.y(), yE = y + rect.height(); y < yE; y += gridSize) {
    QGraphicsLineItem *pQItem
      = new QGraphicsLineItem(rect.x(), y, rect.width() - 1, y);
    pQItem->setPen(gridColor);
    qItemGrp.addToGroup(pQItem);
  }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  // setup GUI
  QWidget qWnd;
  QGridLayout qGrid;
  QLabel qLblL(QString::fromUtf8("Grid as part of scene"));
  qGrid.addWidget(&qLblL, 0, 0);
  QCheckBox qTglGridL(QString::fromUtf8("Show Grid"));
  qGrid.addWidget(&qTglGridL, 0, 1);
  QGraphicsView qGraphView;
  qGrid.addWidget(&qGraphView, 1, 0, 1, 2);
  QLabel qLblR(QString::fromUtf8("Grid painted as background"));
  qGrid.addWidget(&qLblR, 0, 2);
  QCheckBox qTglGridR(QString::fromUtf8("Show Grid"));
  qGrid.addWidget(&qTglGridR, 0, 3);
  Canvas canvas;
  qGrid.addWidget(&canvas, 1, 2, 1, 2);
  qWnd.setLayout(&qGrid);
  qWnd.show();
  // init GUI
  QGraphicsScene qGraphSceneL;
  QGraphicsItemGroup qItemGrid;
  makeGrid(qItemGrid, QRect(0, 0, 320, 240));
  qGraphSceneL.addItem(&qItemGrid);
  qGraphView.setScene(&qGraphSceneL);
  qTglGridL.setCheckState(
    qItemGrid.isVisible() ? Qt::Checked : Qt::Unchecked);
  qTglGridR.setCheckState(
    canvas.gridVisible() ? Qt::Checked : Qt::Unchecked);
  // install signal handlers
  QObject::connect(&qTglGridL, &QCheckBox::stateChanged,
    [&qItemGrid](int state)
    {
      qItemGrid.setVisible(state != Qt::Unchecked);
    });
  QObject::connect(&qTglGridR, &QCheckBox::stateChanged,
    [&canvas](int state)
    {
      canvas.setGridVisible(state != Qt::Unchecked);
    });
  // runtime loop
  return app.exec();
}
```

The following snapshots show the application after start and after resizing:

[image: snapshot of testQGraphicsView-BgGrid after start]

[image: snapshot of testQGraphicsView-BgGrid after resizing]

Comment: Sir can you share this source code with me. because there have some difficulties to understand me.can you share source code with github or can you send me a mail : slstore94@gmail.com

Comment: The gray code box contains the complete C++ source code. The only missing piece is a QMake file as I used a CMake script instead. Copy/paste it and you may use it on your side. If I remember this right: What is published on SO is public domain. So, feel free to use or change it.

Comment: After installing qmake in cygwin, I was able to test a qmake script and updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @eyllanesc I updated the code and documented advantages/weaknesses of both alternatives. Btw. I guess using `QGraphicsScene::drawBackround()` seems to be the "intended way" - I hadn't noticed it before.